# getting error on Enum.GetValues<KnownColor>() how to resolve?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void GetNames()
{
    Color originColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 206, 206, 206);

    // Simplest, but not necessary the best one
        int Distance(Color left, Color right) =>
          Math.Abs(left.R - right.R) +
          Math.Abs(left.G - right.G) +
          Math.Abs(left.B - right.B) +
          Math.Abs(left.A - right.A);
    
        var result = Enum
          .GetValues<KnownColor>()
          .MinBy(color => Distance(Color.FromKnownColor(color), originColor));
    }
```

the error is on:

```
GetValues<KnownColor>
```

The non-generic method 'Enum.GetValues(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: The generic flavor requires .NET5+.  Consider Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))

Comment: @HansPassant MinBy not exist now.  var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
    .MinBy(color => Distance(Color.FromKnownColor(color), originColor));

Comment: MinBy() requires .NET6+.  Maybe you really ought to upgrade your project's target framework version.

Comment: @HansPassant if I want to install the latest .net 8.0 what version should I get ?  .NET 8.0 Long Term Support Tooltip: Long Term Support (LTS) releases have an extended support period (3 years). Use LTS if you need to stay supported on the same version of .NET for longer. Active Tooltip: During the active support period, .NET releases are updated to improve functional capabilities and mitigate security vulnerabilities. x64 | x86 | Arm64
(v8.0.100) x64 | x86 | Arm64
(v8.0.0) Release notes November 10, 2026

Comment: @HansPassant i mean i need the sdk version or runtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type argument for `Enum.GetValues` was added in .NET 5, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0#system-enum-getvalues-1).

So, either upgrade your .NET version to .NET 5+, or pass it as a method parameter like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
```

Unlike the overload that accepts a type parameter, the above returns a generic array rather than an array of `KnownColor`, so you have to cast it.

```
var colors = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
```

Comment: then I don't need all the MinBy part ?  because after the change MinBy not exist.  var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
    .MinBy(color => Distance(Color.FromKnownColor(color), originColor));

Comment: @SharonLeni Both overloads return an array, but without the type parameter, it's probably just a generic array rather than a `KnownColor[]`. You can just cast it and just `MinBy` like usual. I'll update the answer.

Comment: the MinBy not exist yet so just for knowledge, i don't need the MinBy and the Distance part anymore?

Comment: @SharonLeni `MinBy` is LINQ, which can be used for anything that inherits from `IEnumberable`, which includes arrays. If you did the second step, it will show up. Whether or not you need it depends on what you're using it for, which isn't something I can tell you, but if you want the code to work the same as it did before, then yes you need it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to use the GetValues method with `KnownColor` enum, but the GetValues method is not directly available for enums. You can use `Enum.GetValues` and cast the result to an array of `KnownColor`

Try this code:

```
private void GetNames()
{
    Color originColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 206, 206, 206);

    // Simplest, but not necessarily the best one
    int Distance(Color left, Color right) =>
        Math.Abs(left.R - right.R) +
        Math.Abs(left.G - right.G) +
        Math.Abs(left.B - right.B) +
        Math.Abs(left.A - right.A);

    var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
                     .Cast<KnownColor>()
                     .MinBy(color => Distance(Color.FromKnownColor(color), originColor));
}
```